# WebApi in Net Core using RabbitMQ

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I am very new on RabbitMQ World and Microservices Architecture. I've watched some tutorials on youtube how to use rabbitMQ but there are some questions I would like to ask.

1.) If the client post the data to my api controller and my api controller publish the data into queue, what is the proper way to respond the post request while the data is being processed on rabbitMQ? Because from the tutorial, It just returns "Ok (Http Code 200)" even though the data is not still completed yet.

2.) Can consumer subscribe more than 1 queue? If yes, is there any configuration sample on startup.cs?

3.) Is there any sample using rabbitMQ on .NetCore for "Real World" cases? Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's perfectly okey to return 200. That's just one of many tradeoffs for microservices architecture. E.g. from the performance perspective, it's efficient that you can return early with 200 and propagate all the changes asynchronously through the rest of the distributed system. On the other hand, it adds another type of complexity that you need to embrace - Eventual Consistency. This concept kind of describes what you asked about. Let say your client received 200, but if it immediately calls another microservice the client may not see changes introduced by the previous request, because there is a probability that the changes haven't propagated yet. You need to decide whether it's acceptable in your project or not. If not maybe you should redesign how you split your business domain into microservices, trying to group transactionally close to each other entities together in order to mitigate such problems. If you can't really tolerate Eventual Consistency maybe you should give up on microservices for the particular project.
2. Yes it can, you could for example create an implementation of IHostedService for each queue listening for messages and run them in parallel with your asp net core app by registering them in the starutp.cs
3. You'll find this in the repository from the below's links. They use RabbitMQ. Although, there's a bit of abstraction which can make it harder to grasp, it's a great implementation with a bonus of being documented in the free ebook.

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/ - I can't stress enough how this repository helped me with understanding microservices. There's also a free ebook from Microsoft docs about this repo: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/ . They tackle concepts such as Eventual Consistency and asynchronous communication. It's exactly what you look for.

Comment: Hi Michal, thank you for your answer. Noted for no 1 and no 3. Thank you for sharing the link. For no2, do you mind to create the code? Thank you in advance